# Getting private keys to work on windows 7 powershell version 2

Tags: powershell, x509certificate, private-key

Firstly, I know that very similar questions have been asked, but having read through the solutions and modifying my own workflow has not produced the correct results.

I am hoping that by showing the code I am using, someone may be able to point out where I am going wrong. I am trying to import a priate key from my windows 10 machine to my legacy windows 7 with powershell version 2 installed.

The error I am facing is that $cert.hasprivatekey returns true but $cert.privatekey always returns null. However this happens on the windows 10 machine as well so it seems to be a problem generating a key but every guide I have found uses the same syntax!

Here is the code to create the key:

```
        $store = "cert:\CurrentUser\My"

    $params = @{
    CertStoreLocation = $store
    Subject = "CN=Test1"    
    KeyLength = 2048
    KeyAlgorithm = "RSA" 
    KeyUsage = "DataEncipherment"
    Type = "DocumentEncryptionCert"
    KeyExportPolicy = 'Exportable'
    }

    # generate new certificate and add it to certificate store
    $cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate @params

    Get-ChildItem -path $store

    $pwd = ("P@ssword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
    $privateKey = "$home\Documents\Test1.pfx"
    $publicKey = "$home\Documents\Test1.cer"

    # Export private key as PFX certificate, to use those Keys on different machine/user
    Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath $privateKey -Cert $cert -Password $pwd

    # Export Public key, to share with other users
    Export-Certificate -FilePath $publicKey -Cert $cert
```

I have aso tried this to no avail:

```
       $TestCertificate = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject 'TestCertificate' -KeyExportPolicy 'Exportable'
        Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $TestCertificate -FilePath .\TestCertificate.pfx -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString 'TestPassword' -AsPlainText -Force)
```

I am then trying to import the private pfx certificate on windows 7 using the following:

```
     $PfxFilePath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test1.pfx"
    $pwd = ("P@ssword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
    $Password = $pwd

    $absolutePfxFilePath = Resolve-Path -Path $PfxFilePath
    Write-Output "Importing store certificate '$absolutePfxFilePath'..."

     Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
     $cert = New-Object   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
    $cert.Import($absolutePfxFilePath, $Password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")
    $Store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My, 
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::LocalMachine)
    $store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::"ReadWrite")
    $store.Add($cert)
    $store.Close()
```

All ideas welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The key is stored in Key Storage Provider which is not supported by `PrivateKey` property which is completely obsolete. Instead you need to use newer syntax to obtain private key:

```
$key = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($cert)
```

Comment: Hi Crypt32, thank you for your answer. I am a little confused on how to fit this in with my original code to get it to work. Coud I trouble you for an example please?  I think I understand that $cert.hasprivatekey or $cert.privatekey is outdated and that should be removed as a check from my code. Is that correct? Thank you

Comment: I don't see any usage of private key in your code.

Comment: You are correct, but I am testing if there is a private key in my setup script using If($Cert.HasPrivateKey -eq $False -or $Cert.PrivateKey -eq $null){Write-Error "error}

Comment: Where would I use the $key variable you kindly provided to help make this work?

Comment: It is sufficient to check only `HasPrivateKey` value to determine if certificate has associated private key.

Comment: Thanks, I will adapt it. Even though .hasprivatekey returns true, I am still having problems using it. Where would you recommend I change to add the $key = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($cert) ?. Thanks for your help and sorry for all the questions. I am stll trying to work through it

Comment: I still don't know your use case. Your question was about obtaining private key object from certificate. I showed you. How you use it -- it is solely up to your use case.